# how to fix, size of the fancy box(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, fancybox

I did video overlays using fancybox. but the problem is some of my videos are very large. So i want to fix width and height of fancybox as 470X290. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which fancy box are you using. check its documentation. there must be some parameters to set width and height where you create a fancy box.

Comment: I am using fancyBox-1.2.1 version and i don't know how to change?

Comment: $("a.group").fancybox({
 'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
 'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
 'width'  : 600, 
 'height' : 200, 
 'overlayShow' : false
});

Comment: Hey yuzi, sorry man I posted the options for 1.3.
for 1.2+ the options are 'frameWidth' and 'frameHeight'
Check this link http://fancybox.net/api/126
let me know if this works